# npm running task rollbackFailedOptional forever

Tags: npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install a new package via npm. Something like this:

```
 npm install -g connection-test
```

Sadly the console is never finishing the task "rollbackFailedOptional".

I'm behind a proxy which I added to the npm config.
I removed the s from the https of my registry.

Any ideas what could be the issue or how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake in the configuration. Didn't put the https:// in front of the Ip-address of the proxy.